# How to show all divs again when no filter-checkboxes are checked anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a little filter. Depending on the checkboxes you check, it will show boardgames for a certain amount of players and a certain amount of playing time. On first load and first use of the checkboxes, it works the way I want to. But as soon as I uncheck the last checked checkbox so that all of them are unchecked again, the list of boardgames disappears completely instead of the full, unfiltered list being shown again.

I tried to counter this problem by adding the class .reset to each boardgame and make the script at least show alll boardgames/divs with this particular class (that is when no other additional checkboxes/classes are selected). Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The reset button is an extra option by the way, but shouldn't be needed if the filter gets fixed and shows all boardgames as soon as all checkboxes get unchecked again.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 align="center">Boardgamefilter</h3>

<form name="gamesettings">
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="1p">1p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="2p">2p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="3p">3p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="4p">4p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="5p">5p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="6plus">6plus<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="15m">15m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="30m">30m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="45m">45m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="60m">60m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="90m">90m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="120mplus">120mplus
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" name="Un_CheckAll" value="Reset"
onClick="UnCheckAll(document.gamesettings.gamesetting)">
</form>

<br />
<br />

<div id="boardgames">
<div class="reset 1p 2p 15m 30m" style="display: block;">Boardgame A - 1p 2p 15m 30m</div>
<div class="reset 1p 2p 30m 45m" style="display: block;">Boardgame B - 1p 2p 30m 45m</div>
<div class="reset 2p 30m 60m" style="display: block;">Boardgame C - 2p 30m 60m</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('input[name=gamesetting]').change(function(){

        var arr = []
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
           if($(this).is(":checked")){
             arr.push($(this).val())
           }
        })
        var vals = arr.join(".")
        var str = (".") + vals

        $('#boardgames div').hide();
        $('#boardgames div.reset' + (str)).show();

    })    

    function UnCheckAll(chk) {
        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = false ;
        $('#boardgames div').show();
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone see what code should be changed in order to show all boardgames again after all checkboxes get unchecked again? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This script should end in an `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #boardgames div.reset.` when deselecting the last option

Comment: Ah, of course, I see now, Andreas, thanks. Do you happen to know how I could counter this codewise (I'm not quite a javascript/jquery star). If the array is empty, that particluar dot should not be passed along, but how do I do this exactly?

Comment: _"If the array is empty, that particluar dot should not be passed along"_ -> _"If the array is not empty, prepend a dot"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add check for the empty array

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 align="center">Boardgamefilter</h3>

<form name="gamesettings">
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="1p">1p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="2p">2p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="3p">3p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="4p">4p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="5p">5p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="6plus">6plus<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="15m">15m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="30m">30m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="45m">45m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="60m">60m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="90m">90m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="120mplus">120mplus
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" name="Un_CheckAll" value="Reset"
onClick="UnCheckAll(document.gamesettings.gamesetting)">
</form>

<br />
<br />

<div id="boardgames">
<div class="reset 1p 2p 15m 30m" style="display: block;">Boardgame A - 1p 2p 15m 30m</div>
<div class="reset 1p 2p 30m 45m" style="display: block;">Boardgame B - 1p 2p 30m 45m</div>
<div class="reset 2p 30m 60m" style="display: block;">Boardgame C - 2p 30m 60m</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('input[name=gamesetting]').change(function(){

        var arr = []
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
           if($(this).is(":checked")){
             arr.push($(this).val())
           }
        })
        var vals = arr.join(".")
        var str = (".") + vals

        $('#boardgames div').hide();
        if (arr.length) {
          $('#boardgames div.reset' + (str)).show();
        } else {
          $('#boardgames div.reset').show();
        }

    })    

    function UnCheckAll(chk) {
        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = false ;
        $('#boardgames div').show();
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```